# Moving SQL Server database decrease performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just moved a big SQL Server database (about 25G in db file size and 20G in log size) from one computer to another. Then suddenly a query that returns in 1 sec in the old machine will run more than 1 minutes in the newly build machine (much more powerful).

The old machine is a dual core Intel I3 with 4g ram. The new machine is a quad core Intel I7 with 16g ram.

I checked that the indexes are exactly the same.

What could be the reason?

Edits:

Haven't update DB stats. Will do that.
Haven't de-fragment the indexes. Will do that as well.
OS: The old machine runs windows server 2008. The new one runs windows server 2012.
Hard-drive: SSD raid 1. Local physical drive. Partitioned into two logical drive one for DB storage and the other for Log storage.

The new machine is running on full performance settings. It's a single machine, nothing balanced to other machines. 
It's dedicated for this DB task, nothing else is running on the machine.

Comment: What about disk space and storage in general? Is the storage local to the server? is it the same version of the server?

Comment: Perhaps post the exact @@VERSION of each machine's SQL instance. Execution plans can change with the version of the software.

Comment: Failing that perhaps compare query plans?

Comment: Are DB STATS up to date? DB Statistics affect query plans. Try to update.

Comment: What about OS? Any hard drive partioning magic? (RAID or smth) And query plans + analyze statistics are definitely must do, mate ;) For testing purpose, check some other scripts - did the slowed down too?

Comment: You should definitely use [SQLIO](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/09/finding-your-san-bottlenecks-with-sqlio/) to test the drive performance too.

Comment: Check your new machine isn't running on balanced or similar on the power settings. Compare metrics in perfmon. Try to recompile execution plans.

Answer (score 2):

It could be variety of reasons. Is that a local harddrive or networked harddrive?

1. The newer harddisk is slow
2. Ensure that the db file and transaction log are defragged. You would need to stop sql server and perform defrag. You can use something like Contig from Microsoft (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb897428.aspx)
3. Is the newer harddisk filesystem encrypted?
4. Check for antivirus software. If you have enabled realtime filesystem check, it will slow down by a significant factor for some antivirus brands

Most probable reason would be 2 or 4 from above

As a general advice, for better performance, store db file and log files on separate hard disks (not just different partitions).

Comment: hi, are you saying defrag the index or the datafile from file system? thanks

Comment: You should defrag all the files related to your db. That includes the indexes if its stored in separate file. I am talking OS level defrag. Database defrag (sql server maintenance task) will also help here. But since you are using SSD, you wont gain much by defragging.

Comment: SSD write performance drops significantly when the drive is almost full. You might want to check the SSD bench marks for db operations. Paul Randal blog is userful. http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/benchmarking-introducing-ssds-part-1b-not-overloaded-log-file-array search for all the articles by him on SSDs. useful read